# Get-SPContentDatabase export to CSV and include web application url

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, export-to-csv

I'm trying to get a powershell one liner to export the information of all my SharePoint content databases into a CSV file that could then be used as the input for a mounting script.

If i run:

`Get-SPContentDatabase | Select Name, DatabaseServer, MaximumSiteCount, WarningSiteCount | Export-CSV DatabaseExport.CSV`

I get most of the information I need but I can't get the Web Application url. The WebApplication exports as "SPWebApplication Name=*webappname*", where I need the url or ID.

I'm thinking I will need to come up with it in a script, that will add loop through and add the url to the exported CSV... but it would be nice to have this in a one liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Calculate property (a really cool feature of powershell) ! for you one line script ;)

```
Get-SPContentDatabase | select Name, Server, MaximumSiteCount, WarningSiteCount , @{Name="URL";Expression={$_.WebApplication.Url}} | Export-Csv TestDB.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case nobody or you come up with a one-line solution, I will share my version of it:

```
$dbs = Get-SPContentDatabase
$result = @();
foreach($db in $dbs){
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "URL" -Value $db.WebApplication.URL
    $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $db.Name
    $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "DatabaseServer" -Value $db.Server
    $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "MaximumSiteCount" -Value $db.MaximumSiteCount
    $obj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "WarningSiteCount" -Value $db.WarningSiteCount
    $result += $obj
}

$result | Export-Csv .\DatabaseExport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Just add/remove properties if you need. Check out [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spcontentdatabase_properties.aspx) for all the properties that you can use :)

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I had. It just seemed like i should be able to do it in one line of PowerShell.